# Как проверить на laravel, что загружаемый файл картинка не более чем 800х800 и весом не более 500кб?

Tags: php, laravel

Как проверить на laravel, что загружаемый файл картинка не более чем 800х800 и весом не более 500кб?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации:

Проверка размера файла:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'max:500000',
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-size

Проверка разрешения картинки:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'avatar' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200'
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-dimensions